# Object literals in javascript. How to access quoted "prop s" of object?

Tags: javascript

In javascript tutorial I've see the next object definition:

```
var myObject = {
    validIdentifier: 123,
    'some string': 456,
    99999: 789
};
```

What the purpose of such key-value pairs with quoted ones as keys? How one could operate with such values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access them with brackets (called ["bracket notation" or the "subscript operator"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)):

```
myObject['some string']
```

Keys like this must to be quoted because of the space (to avoid syntax errors).

The reasons for doing this are up to the developer. One (of like, a million) examples would be [`Backbone.js`'s `delegateEvents`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents) that maps events and selectors to handler functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use special characters if you put them in a string. For instance, this isn't valid:

```
myObj.prop-one
```

But this is:

```
myObj["prop-one"]
```

This is especially useful when accessing CSS properties on DOM elements, like this:

```
myElement.style["background-color"],
```

when `myElement.style.background-color` is invalid.

Comment: `myElement.style.backgroundColor` works for that last example, but you still get the point.

Answer (score 0):

> What the purpose of such key-value pairs with quoted ones as keys?

Having spaces in names is useful in many circumstances.

```
var people_per_street = {
    "1st Street: [ ... ],
    "Broadway": [ ... ]
    /* etc */
};
```

> How one could operate with such values?

`myObject['validIdentifier'], myObject['some string'], myObject['99999']`

Answer (score 0):

It's a way to group variables-that-logically-belong-to-each-other together.

Access them like this:

```
myObject['some string'];
```